# $\int_0^2 f(2x)dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If f is continuous and $$\int_0^4 f(x) dx = 13$$ Calculate: $$ \int_0^2 f(2x)dx$$

I'm struggling in this exercise. Wouldn't I need to know? $$\int_2^4 f(x) dx$$

Can this $$f(2x)$$ be transformed into $$2 * f (x)?$$

Comment: Let $u=2x$, $du=2dx$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $u=2x$.  Then $du=2dx$, so
$$\int_0^2f(2x)dx=\int_0^4f(u)\dfrac{du}2=\frac12\int_0^4f(u)du.$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, you cannot say something like

$${f(2x)=2f(x)}$$

this is definitely not true for general functions. For example, ${f(x)=x^2}$ would give ${f(2x)=(2x)^2=4x^2=4f(x)}$, not ${f(2x)=2f(x)}$.

---

It's hard to know from your post alone how much you know in regards to things you are allowed to do with integration. If we want to calculate

$${\int_{0}^{2}f(2x)dx}$$

by using the known result

$${\int_{0}^{4}f(x)dx=13}$$

(and we are given ${f(x)}$ is continuous - this is important) - you may use integration by substitution. You may notice that doing ${u=2x}$ in the integral ${\int_{0}^{2}f(2x)dx}$ would give us ${du=2dx\Rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{2}}$. So

$${\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{2}f(2x)dx=\int_{0}^{4}\frac{f(u)du}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{4}f(u)du}$$

(since you can pull out that factor of ${\frac{1}{2}}$ to the front). Now you can use the known result to conclude this is

$${=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{4}f(u)du=\frac{1}{2}(13)=\frac{13}{2}}$$

And so there is the answer.

Comment: Can I consider this equality between integrals because f is continuous?

Comment: @DiegoLima this is correct yes. $f$ being continuous allows you to use Integration by Substitution (also because ${u(x)=2x}$ is differentiable). Have you learned about Integration by Substitution?

Comment: Yes. But I had not understood that such equality could exist. I need to study more hahaha

Comment: $+1$; includes more details than my answer